# My laptop already has a USB-C port, but it doesn't support display output. Can I upgrade it?

Tags: laptop, installation, hardware-rec, docking-station, usb-c

I have a Lenovo Ideapad L340 Gaming Laptop. The laptop has an existing USB-C port, but it is a Gen 1 port and therefore does not support display/video output.

I would like to use my USB-C dock to connect to up to two external monitors, Ethernet, and my mouse, keyboard, and LED mouse pad, so I don't have so many individual things to plug in when I sit at my desk, or unplug when I leave. My question is: is it possible for me to upgrade the USB-C port to a Gen 2 port? And if so, how do I do it/how difficult will it be?

To provide further context, I am reasonably adept at performing simple electronic/wiring tasks (I've upgraded my RAM, I've installed a smart thermostat in my home, things like that) but I would by no means call myself an expert.

Also, I am not looking for a USB-A dock or converter - this laptop uses Gen 1 for all ports, so buying a different dock won't exactly do me any good. I am specifically asking about whether and how I can upgrade the hardware for the USB-C port in order to use a USB-C dock for the purposes listed above.

Comment: Not realistically, and honestly probably not at all. If this was a desktop, you could find a PCIe expansion for this type of thing. For a laptop, you'd need a new PCB with USB Type-C Gen 2, which could possibly mean changing out your entire motherboard, which itself is custom fit to your laptop and thus, you wouldn't be able to find one that fits. Even if you could, it would be very expensive.

Comment: "is it possible for me to upgrade the USB-C port to a Gen 2 port?" - No;  What you want is not possible.  You are correct that purchasing a Dock that does support Gen 2 would not accomplish your task.

Comment: USB-C "gen 1" and "gen 2" is not really the terminology to use.  What you are talking about is USB 3.0 and USB 3.1.  The plug doesn't matter and confuses the problem.  USB 3.0 can very well support a USB-HDMI adapter.. now one vs two external monitors is limited by video ram and not the speed.

Comment: Actually, whether the port is USB 3.2 Gen1, 2, 2x2 or whatever, does not matter _at all_. This is about whether the port can support DisplayPort output, which is entirely independent from any USB versions it may or may not support. In fact, it need not support USB at all.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading the USB port in your laptop isn't happening.

However, despair not, for there may still be a solution for your actual needs. [DisplayLink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayLink)<sup>1</sup> is a technology (and company that implements said technology) that can carry a video signal over USB. Shop around for DisplayLink docks and you'll probably be able to find one that can allow for multiple displays, mouse, keyboard, and Ethernet to all be connected over one cable.

It seems to perform plenty well for office work or videos. If you game a lot or do other work that has high latency sensitivity, keep in mind that the extra overhead from the USB protocol and the extra encoding/decoding *might* have a noticeable effect. It might work just fine for you, but it's something to keep in mind.

---

1. Not to be confused with [Display***Port***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort), a display interface that can be implemented (natively) in USB-C alternate mode. Native DisplayPort will generally provide higher bandwidth, lower latency, and possibly lower system resource use than DisplayPort provided via DisplayLink.